# Servicestack Authentication namespace using SOAP

Tags: .net, api, soap, servicestack

I'm getting this error when using SOAPUI to send an authenticate request to my ServiceStack API.

```
Expecting element 'Authenticate' from namespace 'http://schemas.servicestack.net/types'.. Encountered 'Element' &nbsp;with name 'Authenticate', namespace 'http://correctnamespace.com/schemas/2015/05/MyAPI/'
```

Here's my apphost setup:

```
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            HandlerFactoryPath = "api",
            DefaultContentType = "application/json",
            WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://correctnamespace.com/schemas/2015/05/MyAPI/",
            DebugMode = false,
            UseHttpsLinks = Core.Config.UserRemoteConfig()
        });

        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new CustomAuthProvider()
            })
        {
            IncludeAssignRoleServices = false,
            IncludeAuthMetadataProvider = false,
            HtmlRedirect = null
        });
```

I don't understand why servicestack is expecting the wrong namespace, can anyone help me in understanding how to set the expected namespace to the correct namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your custom ns at the wsdl level, but the type itself is still using its own ns which I assume is the default one "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types". Not sure how you could change those built-in ns, not even sure if that's possible, but you might create your own auth provider with your custom types so you can [set your custom ns](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support)

Comment: Thanks dude.  As a temp fix i just set everything back to the default:  "http://schemas.servicestack.net/types".  We'll make our own auth provider.